# Can't find requests using SoapUI API

Tags: java, api, soapui

I am trying to use the SoapUI API, but I am unable to find the requests using the API that I have in the SoapUI project.

My project tree looks like this:
[image: project tree]

and the code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject("SoapUI/Tests.xml");

        WsdlInterface iface = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project, "SoapUI/Enrollment.wsdl", true)[0];

        System.out.println("\n\n<---------WSDL INTERFACE " + iface.getName() + " IMPORTED---------->\n\n");

        WsdlOperation op = (WsdlOperation)iface.getOperationAt(0);

        System.out.println("Opperation: " + op.getName());
        for(Request r : op.getRequestList()) {
            if(r instanceof WsdlRequest) {
                System.out.println("\t" + r.getName());
            }
        } 

        iface.release();

        System.out.println("\n\nDONE");

        System.exit(0);

    } catch (XmlException | IOException | SoapUIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }


}
```

}

Output:
<---------WSDL INTERFACE Enrollment_v1SoapBinding IMPORTED---------->

Opperation: AsyncEnroll
    Request 1

DONE

It accuratly prints that the operation name is 'AsyncEnroll'. the interface name is changed slightly from 'enrollment_v1HttpBinding' to 'Enrollment_v1SoapBinding'. The big issue, however, is that it only prints a single request called 'Request 1'. It cannot find 'Test1-AsyncEnroll' or 'Test2-AsyncEnroll'.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You should use it by creating a [test suite -> test case and have test step](https://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no one responded so I'll post the workaround I developed.

Even though I couldn't find the responses, everything else seems to be working well. So I just copied the responses into my code, which also allowed me to edit some variables I want users to be able to change.

I don't think this is an ideal solution, but it works.